# Google Sheets - color any cell in a specific range if it contains a comment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a script to color any cell in AE4:last row in AE, orange if it contains a comment (not a note) in the sheet named is "Events".

I realized I need a more obvious way to tell if cells have comments in them, so coloring the cell instead of having just an orange arrow would be much more useful for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interacting with **Comments** doesn't seem to be possible. See the google-apps-script-issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2566), which appears to have been merged into [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1818). You could consider starring the issue(s) to follow possible updates and / or fixes.

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply.

It does seem quite counter intuitive, though, to not allow the interaction with Comments.

I was hoping there was a way to do this automatically. It seems I'll have to manually color the cells in these cases for now.